# Do (Mountable) Rails Engines Inherit Gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance

When I generate a `--mountable` Rails engine, does it automatically inherit all of the parent app's gems (and "assigned" environment `groups`) in the root `Gemfile`, and does the child `Gemfile` allow for additional gems to be added? And should you desire to override the parent's `group` environments, can this be done in the child engine's `Gemfile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mountable engine is just a piece of Rails functionality bundled as a gem.

Gems can have their own dependencies which are declared in the `.gemspec` file.

> Do (Mountable) Rails Engines Inherit Gems?

No. Not really. Since a gem is mounted in an application it can theoretically use any dependency that is present in the application but its not a good idea to rely on implicit dependencies because it does not allow the gem to be tested in isolation.

> And should you desire to override the parent's group environments, can this be done in the child engine's Gemfile?

No. You should not declare a gems depencies in the Gemfile since gems are deployed with the `gem` command - not by Bundler.

See [Clarifying the Roles of the .gemspec and Gemfile](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) for a more detailed explaination from one of the core contributors to Bundler.